# Regex to get words between two _

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I would like a regex which will return words between _

```
   word1_word2_word3_word4_word5
```

I want one regex which will return word3 and another one which will return word4

I have this regex this `_[^_]+_`  start with but did not wok

Comment: What about `word2`? It's also between underscores.

Comment: I need to get word2 and then word3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the string by "_" and just accessing the chunks with index 2 and 3 may be easier and do just what you want.

Comment: Ah, wasn't tagged as Oracle before.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle's Regex flavour, but I'm guessing yours returns "\_word2\_" and "\_word4\_". [^_]+ without the leading and trailing underscores should work.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture those words:

```
(?<(^|_))[^_]+(?=(_|$))
```

It's using a look behind for `_` or start, and a look ahead for `_` or end.
FYI, look behinds/aheads are non-consuming, ie "zero width".